# Incorrect syntax in IF body

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008

I try to create this function which concatenates all rows into one string:

```
CREATE function [dbo].[fn_GetProjectDevelopers] ( 
  @ProjectId         varchar(100)
)
returns varchar
as
begin

DECLARE @DevList varchar

DECLARE @DevName varchar(50)
SET @DevList = '';
DECLARE my_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT DISTINCT ServiceAppointment.OwnerIdName as Name 
                    FROM ServiceAppointment

OPEN my_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM my_cursor INTO @DevName 

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    IF @DevName NOT LIKE '%' + @DevList +  '%'
        BEGIN
            @DevList = @DevName+ ' ' + @DevList
        END
    FETCH NEXT FROM my_cursor INTO @DevName
END

CLOSE my_cursor
DEALLOCATE my_cursor


  return @DevList
end
```

I get these errors:

```
Incorrect syntax near '@DevList'.
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CLOSE'.
Incorrect syntax near 'end'.
```

It's the @DevList in the BEGIN ... END part in the IF body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is this

```
 @DevList = @DevName+ ' ' + @DevList
```

should be this

```
SET  @DevList = @DevName+ ' ' + @DevList
```

Your other problem is

```
DECLARE @DevList varchar
```

Where is the size? that will only be 1 character!!

**however there are better ways to do this**

**Here is  a way without a cursor**

```
DECLARE @DevList varchar(8000)
SET @DevList = '';

SELECT   @DevList = @DevList +  OwnerIdName + ' '
from (select distinct OwnerIdName 
                    FROM ServiceAppointment where OwnerIdName  is not null ) x 

SELECT @DevList
```

Runnable example

```
DECLARE @DevList varchar(8000)
SET @DevList = '';

SELECT   @DevList = @DevList +  name + ' '
from (select distinct name  FROM sysobjects) x 

SELECT @DevList
```

Comment: Thanks, I like your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the SET from the IF statement :)

```
BEGIN
IF @DevName NOT LIKE '%' + @DevList +  '%'
    BEGIN
        SET @DevList = @DevName+ ' ' + @DevList
    END
FETCH NEXT FROM my_cursor INTO @DevName
END
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `SET` keyword:

```
SET @DevList = @DevName+ ' ' + @DevList
```